# Типизация Event в react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, события, mouse-event

```
'use client'

import { useAppContext } from '../../AppContext'
import styles from './approaches.module.css'

export interface props {
  children: React.ReactNode; }


// Компонент вывода блока на главной странице: фильтра и всех астероидов (children)
export default function Approaches({children}: props) {

    const {unit, setUnit } = useAppContext()


    const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLSpanElement>) => {
        setUnit((e.target as HTMLSpanElement).getAttribute("data-unit"))

    }


  return (
    <section className={styles.asteroid}>
        <h3 className={styles.nearbyAsteroids}>Ближайшие подлёты астероидов</h3>
        <div className={styles.filter}>
          <span onClick={handleClick} data-unit='kilometers' className={`${styles.filter__item} ${unit === 'kilometers' ? styles.active : ''}`}>в километрах</span>
          <span> | </span>
          <span onClick={handleClick} data-unit='lunar' className={`${styles.filter__item} ${unit === 'lunar' ? styles.active : ''}`} >в лунных орбитах</span>
        </div>
        {children}
    </section>
  )
}
```

В этом месте:

```
const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLSpanElement>) => {
  setUnit((e.target as HTMLSpanElement).getAttribute("data-unit"))

}
```

Выдает такую ошибку:

```
Аргумент типа "string | null" нельзя назначить параметру типа "SetStateAction<string>".
  Тип "null" не может быть назначен для типа "SetStateAction<string>".
```

Пробовал так проверить:

```
const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLSpanElement>) => {
  if((e.target as HTMLSpanElement).getAttribute("data-unit")) {
    setUnit((e.target as HTMLSpanElement).getAttribute("data-unit"))
  }

}
```

Ошибка все равно не исчезает

Comment: Ну так атрибута может и не быть, по этому там может быть `null`.

Comment: А я же ведь проверяю через If. Ошибку все равно выдает

Comment: Сохраните результат в переменную и потом делайте проверку, TS не маг.

Comment: Вот попробовал. Опять тоже самое(((


` const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLSpanElement>) => {
      const atribut = (e.target as HTMLSpanElement).getAttribute("data-unit")
      if(atribut) {
        setUnit((e.target as HTMLSpanElement).getAttribute("data-unit"))
      }
    }`

Comment: Ну так в вашем коде ничего не изменилось.. Зачем вы при `setUtit` опять берете атрибут? Он же уже есть в переменной.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое. Все заработало.